# Display element divs flex to continue horizontally

Tags: html, css

Hello I have this structure vertical DIVs (two o more "Row" -subtab-) with flex property and inside other flex DIVs work like cols (5 elements o more/less -box-).

CSS:

```css
.tab {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.subtab {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.box {
  flex: 1 0;
  width: 20%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <div class="subtab">
    <div class="box"> 
    </div>
      ...
    <div class="box">  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I had problem with: when max-width: 1000px I want display three boxes (cols) per row, the width 33.33% and all rest of table will be fLexible - the border is not collapse one border and vertical align like using   and look like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your snippet, so we see your issue . column wrap might also require a max-height or height to be set ...

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this easily without the subtabs. Are you trying to group multiple tabs together for a particular style?